# Angularjs base tag and $locationProvider prevents templates to be loaded

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, pretty-urls

I want to remove the `#` on angularjs url. So I followed [this blog](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag).

This is my `.config()` :

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider' function($stateProvider, $locationProvider,) {

     $stateProvider.state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/main.html',
        controller:'mainCtrl'
     })

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

And this is my `<header>` :

```
<head>
    <scripts>....

    <base href="/"> // I ADDED THIS
</head>
```

But when I access the `/` link. Like this `http://localhost/my-app/` it only shows a blank page. There are no error/s on the console so Im assuming that the problem is on the loading of the template. Im using `ui.router`. Someone encountered this problem? Thanks.

Comment: ng-click(go())) and in go $state.go('somewhere') works?

Comment: I don't need any click events, I want this to happen on load of the web app/. @stackg91

Comment: sry I dont really understand what you need that base for can u describe your scenario more If i understand correctly you want to show smth when you access / right? I am just using $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login'); so everthing which is not defined by state ends up on login

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st 
When you use `<base href="/">` yu set ALL relative URLs appends to that path.
So IF your app is aviable at `/my-app/` use `<base href="/my-app/">`
Also you can try relative base href `<base href="./">`, but i don't recomend it.
Now your app is in `http://localhost/my-app/` but base is `http://localhost/`

2nd
When you use html5 routing, you may ensure that webserver does not repsonse other page, but your index.html

3rd, after that [check your JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320878/3861851), maybe cant load template because of base url...

Comment: Nice, but what if Im going to upload it to my server what would be the `<base href="/my-app/">` if the url is www.foo.com?

Comment: than use `<base href="/">` on server and `<base href="/my-app/">` for local dev.

Comment: when I refresh page then get blank page.What is solution for it?I am using ui.routing.

Comment: You should configure webserver, to return index.html on any URL, except for API and static files.